# Forward Declaration vs #import when subclassing

Tags: objective-c, import, include, forward-declaration

I have `MyClassA` which has a property of type `MyClassB`

```
//
//  MyClassA.h
//  

@interface MyClassA : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) MyClassB *myClassB;

@end
```

`MyClassB` has a property `myString`.

```
//
//  MyClassB.h
//  

@interface MyClassB : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *myString;

@end
```

I have `MyClassC` which needs to access `myString` in it's implementation.

Should I -

a) Forward Declare `MyClassB` in `MyClassA.h` and `#import "MyClassB.h"` in `MyClassC.m`

**or**

b) `#import MyClassB.h` in `MyClassA.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should forward declare with `@class` where possible in your header files. The only time you probably wouldn't want to do it is when you're inheriting from a super class or declaring protocol conformance, because the compiler needs to know what is going on in that class or protocol.

For this instance, I would use @class for all your property declarations in your header files, and `#import MyClassB.h` in your MyClassC.m file. That will allow MyClassC to know about all the properties on MyClassB.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this from a slightly different angle ... you need to decide if you want the world to really know about `myClassB` being a property of `MyClassA`. For example, if you may only want to advertise that  `myString` that can be obtained through `MyClassA`. This insulates other classes from knowing the underlying implementation of `myString`. Unless you have a need to expose `MyClassB` you should hide it from the "rest of the world".

In this case you would change MyClassA.h as follows:

```
//
//  MyClassA.h
//  

@interface MyClassA : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *myString;

@end
```

In MyClassA.m, you would do the following.

```
//
//  MyClassA.m
//  

#import "MyClassA.h"
#import "MyClassB.h"

@interface MyClassA()

@property (strong, nonatomic) MyClassB *myClassB;;

@end

@implementation MyClassA

// Other meaningful code omitted

- (NSString *)myString {
    return self.myClassB.myString;
}

@end
```

Note that what I've done here is use an anonymous category to internally define property for `myClassB`.

The key thing here is whether or not it makes sense to not expose `MyClassB` to others. The main advantage of this approach is your code is more malleable. Let's say `myString` gets derived a different way. From a different class or different method altogether. The code which needs to consume `myString` is immunized.

If you need to expose `MyClassB`, then you can either use `@class` as recommended by Tyler above or `#import MyClassB.h` from MyClassA.h. Best practices prescribe forward declaring `@class`. But at times the convenience of not having to remember to import a lot of files within the implementation file can win out. It's your code-base, so you can pick which one works the best for you. I generally use a combination of the two.